# Is there a difference in this code's assignment when it comes to functionality?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

Following a book example, and I wanted to try it myself before looking at the answer. My answer was different than the book.

1. Is example 1 better or example 2?
2. Are they equally good?
3. Main question: Is there any reason to perform example 1 vs example 2?
4. Is one considered better programming?

Example 1)

```
        {

            Console.WriteLine("How many pills do you take per day?");

            int pillsPoppedPerDay = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(pillsPoppedPerDay);
        }
```

Example 2)

```
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many pills do you take per day?");

            string pillzPoppedPerDay = Console.ReadLine();
            int PillzPoppedPerday = int.Parse(pillzPoppedPerDay);

            Console.WriteLine(pillzPoppedPerDay);
        }

(source is a slight variation of from : C# Programming Yellow Book, Rob Miles)
```

Comment: Both are bad from the standpoint that if the user enters 'I like pills', the program will crash.  You should use `TryParse` versions when dealing with users.  Otherwise it is large a matter of opinion which is "better'

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Not the focus of the question. It also would need way more changes then that. Like a do...while loop.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I just started the book. I'm sure the author will teach exits soon(or whatever is necessary for the program not to crash). I will experiment with what you said, and thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Christopher I'll be learning about loops soon Christopher. Once I learn it, I'll see if I can change the code. Thank you!!

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp is correct about neither of them being good programming, as they don't handle bad user input. However, ignoring that, both styles (define a variable vs no extra variable) have uses -- for example, you might want to define a variable if you need to do multiple actions using the raw input. In your short example, you're only using the raw input once, so there isn't any need to store it.

Comment: @Herohtar This was exactly what I wanted to hear. In the future, I'll consider if I need multiple actions.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally they are identical. Indeed in release build, there is a decent chance they **are** identical. The JiT Compiler and general Compiler Optimisations *love* to cut out underused temporary variables like `string pillzPoppedPerDay`.

For debugging and readability*, I prefer example 2. Having more then 1 Dot in a codeline really just makes the debugging unessesarily hard. And as I said, in release it propably ends up the same MSIL anyway. There is nothing to worry about a barely used temporary variable to slow things down in release.

*Thanks Bizhan

Comment: Once I get 15 rep points I can give you an upvote. Thank you.